# Spring boot , CrudRepository findbyid or findOne is not getting One to many table details of role table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long  id;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    private String username;

    @Transient
    private String passwordConfirm;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Role
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY ,cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private Role role;

    public User() {
    }

    public Long  getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }


    @Transient
    public String getPasswordConfirm() {
        return passwordConfirm;
    }

    public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
    }


}




@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Role.findAll", query="SELECT r FROM Role r")
public class Role implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="role", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private List<User> users;

    public Role() {
    }

    public Long  getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return this.users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public User addUser(User user) {
        getUsers().add(user);
        user.setRole(this);

        return user;
    }

    public User removeUser(User user) {
        getUsers().remove(user);
        user.setRole(null);

        return user;
    }

}
```

---

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository <User, Long> {
```

---

```
public UserDto getUserDetailsById(Long userId)  throws commonException  {
        //ArrayList<UserDto> arr = new ArrayList<>();   
        User user = userRepository.`findOne`(userId);

            UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
            userDto.setId(user.getId());
            userDto.setUsername(user.getUsername());
            userDto.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            userDto.setPassword(user.getPassword());
            userDto.setRoleId(user.getRole().getId());
            userDto.setRoleName(user.getRole().getName());
           // arr.add(userDto);

        return userDto;


    }
```

find by Id is not getting role details by using user object.lazy initialization is not happening.When I use to get user ID from user object, I can not get role details.
userDto.setRoleId(user.getRole().getId()); is having null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `User` entity, you have configured the `Role` collection to load lazily. Therefore when you first call `user.getRole()`, you get a proxy object. If you want to call methods on the proxy object that need to fetch data, you should initialize the proxy. There is a technique to initialize it. Try the following:

Before the following line of code

`userDto.setRoleId(user.getRole().getId());`

add the following;

`user.getRole().size();`

Comment: While that works, my suggestion (as presented in my answer) is for cases where you _know_ an association is needed, why not use a join-fetch instead and avoid the unnecessary second database call which introduces unnecessary performance overhead.

Comment: No, the point is to lazily load the collection - fetch it only when it is needed. The OP could have very well eager fetched it. But that's not the goal.

Comment: You misunderstood.  I'm not suggesting that he change the mapping from LAZY to EAGER, I'm suggesting that instead of using lazy loading and having `#getRole()` load the association when accessed for this particular business case that instead the business case drives a repository method that forces loading the `User` _with_ the `Role` association in a single query using join fetching.  Your advice is precisely why people complain Hibernate is slow and why ORMs are bad.  That's because people aren't optimizing for their use cases.

Answer (score 0):

For situations where you know that you *need* a particular association, its generally recommended that you specify that the association be join-fetched.

If the association is optional, you'd use something like:

```
FROM User u LEFT JOIN FETCH u.role WHERE u.id = :userId
```

If the association is not-optional, you could improve the above by specifying an inner join like:

```
FROM User u JOIN FETCH u.role WHERE u.id = :userId
```

With Spring data, you can use the `@Query` annotation on methods and specify the JPQL/HQL above to suit your needs.